# Why 'equals' method is third person singular?

Tags: methods, naming

Why 'equals' method is third person singular...?

I think.. it means that I WILL SEE THE OBJECT AS THIRD PERSON.

yeah..I also agree with it.

Then.. why trim, add methods are not third person singular?

It makes me very confused :'(

Actually I sometimes thought that it may be natural for people who use languages that has grammatical difference among 1st, 2nd and 3rd person, because my language, Korean, has no grammatical difference among them.

So.. please give me answers :D

Comment: I'd chalk this up to being a nuance of the English language more than anything else...

Comment: "x equals y", but "trim x" - it would not be grammatically correct to say "x equal y" or "trims x".

Comment: And they never write `vec.reserves(100)` !

Answer (score 3):

I think because `Equals` is boolean and takes another object as parameter, it makes a good semantic. A common usage is:

```
if(a.Equals(b)) {}
```

And it's beautiful.

`Trim()` is a kind of order you give to the object. it's like "do that stuff". Following this way, `Equals` should be something like `TellMeIfYouAreEqualTo`:P

Comment: I think the key is on the boolean matter of the method. It makes sense something like ´connection.IsOpen´ and not for an order like `connection.Open()`.

Comment: Thank you :D. actually if the method returns boolean, I usually prefer the name that starts with is- and does- things. But now, I think it may be the naming convention that used in procedural programming. Anyway.. thank you for your answer: D